# Joining 2 Tables using Linq to return as list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

**Here's my WebGrid Code:**

```
@grid.Table(
            tableStyle: "table table-responsive table-bordered",
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(format:@<text> <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" code="@item.SubjectName"  id="Check_@item.SubjectCode" value="Check_@item.Schedule"  /></text>, header: "Check"),
                grid.Column(columnName: "SubjectCode", header: "SubjectCode"),
                grid.Column(columnName: "SubjectName", header: "SubjectName"),
                grid.Column(columnName: "DescriptiveTitle", header: "DescriptiveTitle"),
                grid.Column(columnName: "TotalUnits", header: "Units"),
                grid.Column(columnName: "Schedule", header: "Schedule"),
                grid.Column(columnName: "Instructor", header: "Instructor"),
                grid.Column(columnName: "Room", header: "Room")
            )

        )
```

**Here's what's on my controller:**

```
using (dc)
        {
            var v = (from a in dc.Subjects
                     from b
                     in dc.Curricula
                          .Where(o => a.SubjectCode == o.CourseCode)
                          .DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where
                            a.SubjectCode.Contains(search) ||
                            a.SubjectName.Contains(search) ||
                            a.Curriculum.DescriptiveTitle.Contains(search) ||
                            a.Schedule.Contains(search) ||
                            a.Instructor.Contains(search) ||
                            a.Room.Contains(search)
                     select new { Subject = a, Curriculum = b}
                     );

            totalRecord = v.Count();
            v = v.OrderBy(x => x.Curriculum.Year).ThenBy(x => x.Curriculum.Sem);
            return v.ToList();
        }
```

I'm having problem on foreign data ("DescriptiveTitle","TotalUnits") to be called in webgrid. I've tried other suggested codes that I've found but still not working.

I tried joining the 2 table using linq but the line:

```
return v.ToList();
```

Is in error. I appreciate if someone can help me.

`CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: UESLProject.Subject Subject, UESLProject.Curriculum Curriculum>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UESLProject.Subject>' UESLProject C:\Users\jerome agda\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UESLProject\UESLProject\Controllers\AccountController.cs 162 Active`

Comment: please add the exception of the error

Comment: What have you defined as the return type for this method?

Comment: @tom Hi thank you for your response. Can you teach me how to add that exception cause I don't have any idea how.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm sorry my post was incomplete. It will return to this

`int totalRecord = 0;
            var data = GetSubjects(search, sort, sortdir, out totalRecord);
            ViewBag.TotalRows = totalRecord;
            ViewBag.search = search;
            return View(data);`

Comment: That is not what I mean. Your code returns a list of anonymous type so what is the method signature? What is the error? Is it a compile error or runtime error?

Comment: @Crowcoder sorry for that. Here's the error `CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: UESLProject.Subject Subject, UESLProject.Curriculum Curriculum>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UESLProject.Subject>' UESLProject C:\Users\jerome agda\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UESLProject\UESLProject\Controllers\AccountController.cs 162 Active
`

Comment: Please note you are able to edit your question instead of putting more detail in the comments. You are not returning what your method is supposed to return. A less complex analogy is if you returned a `DateTime` when the method signature returns a `string`. Figure out what you really want to return and make that happen.

Comment: try to remove some parts of the linq query and check witch line causes the error. For example try remove the where block. And add the rest of your asp.net mvc controller code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the `return` statement itself, but the actual type which your method excepts to be returned which is `UESLProject.Subject` and you return a list of anonymous types. If you need to return a list of objects which contain both a `Subject` and a `Curriculum`, then you will need to change the signature of your method and make a separate class wrapping these two (unless you want to use a key value paired collection or `Tuple`)

Here is a short example:

```
class Wrapper
{
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public Curriculum Curriculum { get; set; }
}

List<Wrapper> YourMethodName(...)
{
    ...
        {
            var v = (from a in dc.Subjects
                     from b
                     in dc.Curricula
                          .Where(o => a.SubjectCode == o.CourseCode)
                          .DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where
                            a.SubjectCode.Contains(search) ||
                            a.SubjectName.Contains(search) ||
                            a.Curriculum.DescriptiveTitle.Contains(search) ||
                            a.Schedule.Contains(search) ||
                            a.Instructor.Contains(search) ||
                            a.Room.Contains(search)
                     select new Wrapper { Subject = a, Curriculum = b});

            totalRecord = v.Count();
            v = v.OrderBy(x => x.Curriculum.Year).ThenBy(x => x.Curriculum.Sem);
            return v.ToList();
}
```